# angularJS $timeout function used and page reloading on service calls

Tags: angularjs

I have used `$timeout` to call an angular JS service in every 5 seconds. But it leads to a page or cursor reload in my application. Can anyone assist me to stop the page reload?

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {

  var loadTime = 1000, //Load the data every second
    errorCount = 0, //Counter for the server errors
    loadPromise; //Pointer to the promise created by the Angular $timout service

  var getData = function() {
    //console.log('http://httpbin.org/delay/1?now=' + Date.now());
    $http.get('http://httpbin.org/delay/1?now=' + Date.now())

    .then(function(res) {
      $scope.data = res.data.args;

      errorCount = 0;
      nextLoad();
    })

    .catch(function(res) {
      $scope.data = 'Server error';
      nextLoad(++errorCount * 2 * loadTime);
    });
  };

  var cancelNextLoad = function() {
    $timeout.cancel(loadPromise);
  };

  var nextLoad = function(mill) {
    mill = mill || loadTime;

    //Always make sure the last timeout is cleared before starting a new one
    cancelNextLoad();
    loadPromise = $timeout(getData, mill);
  };


  //Start polling the data from the server
  getData();


  //Always clear the timeout when the view is destroyed, otherwise it will keep polling and leak memory
  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    cancelNextLoad();
  });

  $scope.data = 'Loading...';
});
```

Comment: Hi, could you add your code so we could take a deeper look? Thanks

Comment: @pat Myron I have added the code that am using please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure `loadPromise` exists before cancelling it:

```
var cancelNextLoad = function() {
    ̶$̶t̶i̶m̶e̶o̶u̶t̶.̶c̶a̶n̶c̶e̶l̶(̶l̶o̶a̶d̶P̶r̶o̶m̶i̶s̶e̶)̶;̶
    loadPromise && $timeout.cancel(loadPromise);
};
```